# Can we use normCounts(RUVr) output to calculate TPM?

Tags: r, dataframe, batch-normalization, rna-seq

I have used `RUVr()` from RUVSeq R packages, to correct batch in my data, now I would like to use the corrected table to calculate TPM.

Can I use `normCounts()` to extract batch corrected data for TPM?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of extracting batch-corrected data, the normCounts function from the RUVSeq package is designed to normalize read counts.

The normalization factors for each sample can be obtained with the help of the calcNormFactors function, which you can then use to calculate the TPM (transcripts per million) values for your data. Here's an illustration:

```
library(RUVSeq)

# Your batch-corrected data
bc_data <- # ...

# Obtain normalization factors
factors <- calcNormFactors(bc_data)

# Calculate TPM values
tpm_values <- tpm(bc_data, factors)
```

Comment: Thank you ! bc_data is normCounts () ? because the out put of RUVr () that I used is SeqExpressionSet  format including : count, normalizationcounts and offset. Also what kind of R package is tpm() ?